# JPA/JPQL message error syntax

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

people!

I writting code JPA/HQL and run, but it´s appear message of error. say:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [Select t.disciplina.nomeDisciplina, n.notaFinal From (Select f.notas as notas, sum(f.f1 + f.f2 + f.f3 +f.f4) as soma from Frequencia f group by f.notas) subquery inner join subquery.notas n inner join n.aluno1 a inner join n.turma1 t inner join a.usuario u where u = ?1], line 1, column 54: unexpected token [(].Internal Exception: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.InvalidIdentifierException
```

I create HQL(query) using clause subquery, see in below.

```
 public List<Object[]> getListNotasFrequencia(Usuario u) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

        List<Object[]> lista = new Vector<Object[]>();

        String query = "Select t.disciplina.nomeDisciplina, n.notaFinal "
               + " From (Select f.notas as notas, sum(f.f1 + f.f2 + f.f3 +f.f4) as soma from Frequencia f group by f.notas) subquery  "
                + " inner join subquery.notas n"
                + " inner join n.aluno1 a"
                + " inner join n.turma1 t"
                + " inner join a.usuario u"
                + " where u = ?1"; 

        try {
            lista = em.createQuery(query).setParameter(1, u).getResultList();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

I already bug this code many times, but same message of error.

Please! You help or hint about this code. I´m beginning to learn this JPA/JPQL.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the sub-select in the FROM clause, this is not supported by JPA.  EclipseLink does have some level of support for this, but then you continue to alias relationships from this non-existing object, so I can't see how you expect this to work.

Either rework the query to just use normal joins, or use a native SQL query.